# Atualizar string dentro de objeto dentro de array dentro de objeto dentro de array no MongoDB com Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Preciso atualizar o valor de "title" utilizando o "_id" destacado.

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "620fd81c991c992434131637"
},
"name": "Novo quadro",
"owner_email": "botelhojoao94@gmail.com",
"invited_emails": [],
"lists": [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "620fda7b991c992434131643"
    },
    "title": "teste",
    "items": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "620fdfda991c99243413164c"
        },
        "title": "Novo cartão",
        "description": "",
        "color": ""
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
db.collection.update({
  name: "Novo quadro"
},
{
  $set: {
    "lists.$[listsDoc].items.$[itemsDoc].title": "Novo cartão atualizado"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "listsDoc._id": ObjectId("620fda7b991c992434131643")
    },
    {
      "itemsDoc._id": ObjectId("620fdfda991c99243413164c")
    }
  ]
})
```

você também pode fazer um teste:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/VHznBg_8rQu

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).